# Remove Case sensitivity When Searching through JSON Data: PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to fetch the data from the list which is having same Hospital Name,
but the problem is that I am sending a capital case letters in my query. But the json data contain uncased data eg. I am searching " ASDF HOSPITAL" and the JSON data contains the value as "Asdf hospital". the Query doesnot show any data based on that name. 
but if I manually type "Asdf hospital" on the url it shows the data in the page

Here is the php query I am using .

```
$hospitalName = "ASDF HOSPITAL" ;

<a href="byhospital.php?hname=<?php echo urlencode($hospitalName); ?>">
```

the JSON is in this form :

```
[{"name":"Lorem ipsun",
"emailid":"lorem@ipson.com",
"contactno":null,
"street":"asd",
"state":"asd",
"pincode":"asd",
"country":"Bermuda",
"city":"asd",
"hospitalName":"Asdf hospital",
"gender":"Female"}, 
//and many more]
```

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your query case-insensitive by converting the strings to lowercase before comparing:

- `Asdf hospital` becomes `asdf hospital`
- `ASDF HOSPITAL` becomes `asdf hospital`
- Now when compared they will be the same.

Comment: While lower casing is fine for English, care should be taken that this isn't equal to a case insensitive check for every locale